# Error Loading State Dictionary in PyTorch: TypeError Encountered

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I'm encountering an issue while trying to load the state dictionary in PyTorch. Here's a breakdown of my situation:

1. I have a model named model_fg
2. During training, I return its parameters using `model_fg.parameters()`.
3. I use the Adam optimizer in training with the following line of code:

   `state = optim.Adam(params, lr=lr)`
   where params is of type `<class 'generator'>`.
4. In the evaluation phase, I attempt to load the trained parameters using:

   ```
   model.load_state_dict(trained_params)
   ```

But I encoutere the error:

```
TypeError: Expected state_dict to be dict-like, got <class 'generator'>
```

I believe the issue stems from params being a generator rather than a dictionary. I'm considering converting the generator to a dictionary, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

How to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe the issue stems from params being a generator rather than a dictionary

You are correct, the object you have is a generator while the [`load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict) method expects a *dict*. The generator contains the parameters as an *array* of parameters while the dictionary contains each layer name - parameters *associations*. Converting a generator to a dictionary is not possible because a generator has no information about which parameters correspond to which layer, ie. in general you wouldn't be able to assign each parameter to the correct layer of the target model.

Comment: What I tried is I returned the model and rreturned the model.parameters() as a list. So in trainig phase I used the list directly and for testing phase I created an empty dictionary and then
`for name, param in model.named_parameters():
 trained_params_dict[name] = param`
and then I loaded the trained parameters using load_state_dict by writing
`model.load_state_dict(trained_params_dict)`
Is it ok to do like that?

Comment: Why don't you use the correct method to export your parameters [`state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict)? Calling this on your model will return a dictionary of parameters.

Comment: I  tried to send `model.sate_dict.values() `.  It is resolving the issue but training is not being done at all . When I tried above procedure its happening but dont know if it is valid or not?

Comment: I am a bit lost as to what you are doing. If you want to export/import parameters, then simply use `state_dict` and `load_state_dict`, respectively. What are you doing right now?